# angular treats delayed server response as an empty response

Tags: angular, popup, response, httpresponse

i'am trying to receive a response that takes time from my API and display it as an alert in my angular app.
so far my code looks like this :

component.ts

```
      exploit(form: NgForm) {

   this.vulnsService.exploit(form.value).subscribe((data : any[]) => {
   if(data) {
     alert(data);
   }
   else{
   alert("some error occurred!");
}

 });

  }
```

service.ts

```
     exploit(result1:object) {
  return this.http.post<any>(Constants.node_url+'/exploit/launch', {token: this.usertoken, result1: result1})
    .map(data => {
      return data;
    });
}
```

the request executes without a problem and I can receive the response if I send it with postman but in angular I receive the error empty post response from server.

Comment: delayed answer means a couple seconds or 2 min?

Comment: What authentication scheme are you using? `token: this.usertoken` doesn't look like the correct way to send the token.

Comment: Delayed answer like 3 minutes, the token is not the problem ,it works with other routes.